# Log Transformation in Growth Mixture Model (Mplus user)

Tags: latent-variable, logarithm, growth-mixture-model

I am using parallel process growth mixture modeling to estimate bidirectional longitudinal dynamics between pain (0-100 theoretical range of values) and sleep measures (0-20 theoretical range of values). Conceptually speaking if I log transform both of these raw measures and then regress their latent variables (intercept and slope) on each other, should I interpret that model estimates as percentage change in x that is linked to percentage change in y. In other words, should I refer to this relationship as to elastic?

Comment: If you have 0's then, of course, a pure log transform will not work. Are there any actual 0's? If so, what are you doing with  them?

Comment: With log transformed data such interpretation is correct.

Comment: @peter thanks for pointing out, I don't have 0's so log transformation did generate reasonable values